# Cocotron with pyobjc?

Tags: python, windows, cocoa, pyobjc, cocotron

I'm in the planning stages of developing a cross platform (Mac & Windows) app. Performance is not an issue, and Python would be a good fit for the problem domain. I'm a Cocoa developer with pyojc experience. Cocotron looks appealing, but has anyone used Cocotron with pyojbc?

If not suppose the alternatives are either Cocotron with Objective-C or Python with wxwidgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the performance is not an issue, then why not to use just python **without** obj-c? [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) will provide native look and feel on both Windows, Mac OS and Linux. And it's easy to make distributions for different OSes with [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) and [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html) (and linux users have python anyway :-).

BTW: there is a great example of wxPython open-source application - [Editra](http://editra.org/) text editor. Also, the author of this program wrote a nice **[book](https://www.packtpub.com/wxpython-2-8-application-development-cookbook/book)** on development of cross-platform apps with wxPython. <sub>I'm currently reading it and I enjoy it's short and laconic style. If you want to buy this book - you can complete a survey on the publisher's site and get 50% discount :-) that's what I did.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, although not the answer to what I asked I think it was an answer to what I should have asked. :) My thinking was that I didn't want to learn a few framework, but after doing some research it looks like wxPython is probably the path of least resistance for what I am trying to do (the app will be commercial, but won't set the world on fire so pyqt is out.) 
Thanks for the links, especially the book. Now I just have to figure out which of the several IDEs and GUI builders is best. I've used Komodo in the past, but for CLI apps.